# Jquery dd selecting

Tags: jquery, html

If I have the bellow code, is it possible to select 1st, 2nd and 3rd dd separately. For instance if I wanted to change the sub price to 30, the shipping to 10 and the total to 40, how would I select each dd separately in jquery? I know I could just add classes and do via that, I was just wondering if there is another way of doing it.

```
<dl class="cart">
  <dt>Sub-Total:</dt>
    <dd>10.00</dd>
  <dt>Shipping</dt>
    <dd>5.00</dd>
  <dt>Total:</dt>
    <dd>15.00</dd>
</dl>
```

Also how would I add in jquery

```
  <dt>Discount</dt>
    <dd>-5.00</dd>
```

Right above the Total dt

Comment: @TroyCosentino No, that's not true, as demonstrated already by four other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newDD = '<dt>Discount</dt><dd>-5.00</dd>';

$('dd', '.cart').eq(0).text(30);
$('dd', '.cart').eq(1).text(10);    
$('dd', '.cart').eq(2).text(40);    

$('dt', '.cart').last().before(newDD);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5ntF7/1/)

Comment: @JezenThomas: curious if there are any benefits over `.cart dd`?

Comment: @zerkms - [Sure is much faster, since selectors are always matched right to left](http://jsperf.com/context-vs-one-selector). However, I wouldn't use it. Legibility is more important IMO (unless we're dealing with a very large data set).

Comment: @Joseph Silber: which is *much" faster?!

Comment: The one with the selector split up.

Comment: In principle, there are performance benefits. Depending on the context though, these benefits may be negligible. It's faster, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: The Discount need to be 'Right Above' the Total

Comment: If you insist on splitting up the selector, I'd rather use `$('.cart').find('dd')`. Easier to read.

Comment: @Neverever - you're right, misread that, was sure it was before all the others. Edited it !

Answer (score 1):

The selector returns an array of matched elements. Just use an index to get the one you want.

```
$("dd")[0] gives you the first one.
```

Alternatively, you can use the nth-child selector

```
$("dl dd:nth-child(1)")
```

Comment: `$("dd")[0]` will give you the raw DOM element. This is not what the OP wants. As pointed out by others, `$("dd").eq(0)` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Neverever/37hSb/

```
// Update Price
var updatedPrice = [10, 30, 40]

$("dl.cart > dd").each(function(idx, elm) {
   $(elm).text(updatedPrice[idx]);
});

// Insert Discount
$("<dt>Discount</dt><dd>-5.00</dd>")
   .insertBefore("dl.cart > dt:last");​
```